# Spring Cloud Config Server with Git - Cannot clone or checkout repository connect timeout

Tags: spring, git, timeout, config, connect

I'm doing POC on Spring Cloud Config Server with GIT.

Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE
Java 1.8
Spring Tool Suite
https://github.com/kishornpatil/

I have set the STS proxies correctly in Network Connections.

I have `http.sslverify = false`

I get following exceptions when I request `"localhost:8888/health"`

> 2017-05-18 11:11:15.714 ERROR 9608 --- [nio-8888-exec-4]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot clone or checkout repository]
>   with root cause
>
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92]    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92]    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_92]

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you should at least post your code

Comment: @MikhailLobanov It was simple POC, i only added the annotation on spring application class. In my next question post I will definitely include code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add pass the https proxy as VM arguements and it worked.

-Dhttps.proxyHost=
-Dhttps.proxyPort=

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue with spring cloud config server. You need to add an additional property:

`spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip-ssl-validation = true`

in the `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in adding repo url with branch try adding without branch name. i mean only repo name without `slash` `/` also.

like this :

```
https://github.com/abdabughazaleh/limits-services
```